# Code to lock specific point of graphic to another graphic

Tags: website-design

Is there code to lock specific point of graphic to another graphic or point on a page, so that no matter what device it shows on (or how the page is resized) the graphic on the top stays linked in the same location relative to the graphic or point on the page below it?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to combine two graphics into one image.

Comment: You can do this using CSS and use relative and absolute position. Hard to know exactly what you want to do without seeing an example. Stack Overflow has plenty of questions on this topic: [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent?rq=1)